# Scrape using cherrio node.js

Tags: node.js, express

How do i scrape the project source below one by one?

The project source

```
<div class="textbox">
    <div class="boxtitle">Theme</div>
<div class="genreitem"><a href="link">Cat</a></div>
<div class="genreitem"><a href="link">Dog</a></div>
<div class="genreitem"><a href="link">Zebra</a></div>
<div class="genreitem"><a href="link">Giraffe</a></div>
<div class="genreitem"><a href="link">Anjing</a></div>
</div>
```

Code

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

function runRequest() {
  request('http://www.javlibrary.com/en/genres.php', function(error, response, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body, { ignoreWhitespace: true, xmlMode: true });

    $('div.textbox').each(function(i, html) {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
  });
}

runRequest();

app.listen(3030, (err) => {
  console.log("Running on port 3030");
});
```

the result on terminal `Cat Dog Zebra Giraffe Anjing`

How do i get it one by one?

Answer (score 1):

`.text` returns dom objects (and its children's texts).
With `div.textbox` you're selecting parent element of the text you are logging as output

Use  `$('div.textbox > .genreitem')` selector to pick divs that containts text. 
and you can reach out text of each by index like

```
$($('div.textbox > .genreitem')[1]).text() => Dog
$($('div.textbox > .genreitem')[4]).text() => Anjing
```

Comment: cuz when you pick an element with $('div.textbox > .genreitem')[1] 
its a pure dom object. you have to wrap it into jquery to use .text()